# Class-constrained protocols don't adopt MainActor

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swift-concurrency

If I declare this protocol and model:

```
protocol SubScene: UIViewController {
  func doSomething()
}

struct Model {
  let subScene: SubScene

  func longCalculation() async {
    // Some long-running operation...
    await subScene.doSomething()
  }
}

class MyVC: UIViewController, SubScene {
  func doSomething() {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: nil)
  }
}

let myVC = MyVC()
let model = Model(subScene: myVC)
Task.detached {
  await model.longCalculation()
}
```

I've declared a protocol that is restricted to `UIViewController`, and a model which calls the protocol's `doSomething()` method from an async context. Since `UIViewController` is a `MainActor`, my expectation is that `doSomething()` should get called on the main thread.

However, it does not. In fact the `await` keyword results in a warning from Swift that it is not calling an async method. And empirical testing shows that `doSomething()` will often end up being called on some other thread.

I can fix that by annotating `doSomething()` as a `MainActor`:

```
protocol SubScene: UIViewController {
  @MainActor func doSomething()
}
```

This gets rid of the Swift warning and also results in `doSomething()` getting called on the correct thread.

Is this the correct approach, or is there another way that I could be doing this that avoids having to sprinkle all of my protocol methods with `@MainActor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, alternatively, mark the entire protocol as `@MainActor`, e.g.,

```swift
@MainActor protocol SubScene: AnyObject {
    func doSomething()
}
```

That avoids the need to declare each conforming method individually.